# in android array list is not getting validated

Tags: arraylist, custom-adapter

```
 sbtbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

//try to do validate this array list which coming from CustomAdpater if this Array list is empty then code will return and show the Toast but it  showing any Toast Data Inserted

```
                          {
                              @Override
                              public void onClick(View v) {

                                  final String dbName = "/data/data/" + getClass().getPackage().getName() + "/sync.bdb.db";
                                  if (productListAdapter.getList().toString().equals("")) {
                                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please insert data into list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                      return;
                                  }
                                  helper.savePurchaseList(productListAdapter.getList(), invoiceNo.getText().toString());
                                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                              }
                          }

);
```

Comment: anyone can help me with this code